# É uma pena mesmo?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, gênero

Em várias frases que tem o termo "mesmo" ao final, eu teria esperado ver "mesma", pelo fato do substantivo antecedente ser feminino. Por exemplo, eu preferiria usar "é uma pena mesma."  (Por favor corrija qualquer outro erro que eu cometer.)

Entretanto, uma busca no Google revela muitos usos de "pena mesmo". A busca para "pena mesma" só produz exemplos da frase específica "pena de si mesma". Assumo, por isso, que "pena mesmo" seja o certo, ainda que eu não entenda a gramática. É fato, então, que geralmente "mesma" não poderá aparecer em tais construções? Se for esse o caso, alguém poderia por favor me dizer por quê?

Comment: Complementando as respostas abaixo, nota que *é uma pena mesmo* = *é mesmo uma pena*, o que mostra que *mesmo* é aqui um advérbio (invariável) e não um adjetivo.

Answer (score 7):

*Editado:*
O correto seria: *"É uma pena mesmo"*, pois a palavra *mesmo* desempenha papel de **advérbio**, sendo invariável. Nesse caso, *mesmo* dá ideia de "realmente", "exatamente", "de fato", ou seja, a frase ficaria *"É realmente uma pena"*.

No entanto, *mesmo* possui vários significados no português (e pode ser escrito como *mesma(s)* em alguns casos):

---

### Advérbio

Nesse caso, *mesmo* é **invariável**, não aceitando flexão. É o caso tratado acima, dá ideia de *"realmente"*, *"exatamente"*, *"de fato"*:

- Essa nota é **mesmo** verdadeira?
- É aqui **mesmo**, nesse lugar paradisíaco que desejo passar minhas férias.
- Elas trocaram **mesmo** a lâmpada.

*Editado:*
**NOTA:** como o próprio @Jacinto falou (e concordo com ele), um mesmo advérbio pode ser classificado de diferentes formas dependendo do seu sentido na frase. Fontes mais confiáveis para se obter os usos de *mesmo* seriam dicionários como: [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/mesmo/), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/mesmo) e [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mesmo)

---

### Conjunção subordinativa adverbial concessiva (e locução conjuntiva)

Nesse caso, *mesmo* é **invariável**, não aceitando flexão. Pode ser substituído por outras conjunções como "embora", "apesar de", "por mais que":

- **Mesmo** sendo pobre, nunca desistiu de sonhar. (conjunção)
- Eu não desistirei desse plano **mesmo que** todos me abandonem. (locução conjuntiva)
- **Mesmo** triste, continuarei sorrindo! (conjunção)

---

### Pronome demonstrativo

Usado com valor de substantivo:

- Andei de bicicleta e caí, **o mesmo** aconteceu com a minha irmã. (o mesmo fato)
- Na semana passada, choveu torrencialmente. Dizem que **o mesmo** ocorrerá nos próximos dias. (a mesma coisa)
- **O mesmo** que eu disse a ela, também disse a você. (a mesma coisa)

**NOTA:** Não consegui encontrar algo conclusivo sobre a flexão nesses casos, mas acredito que não haja.

---

### Adjetivo

Nesse caso, *mesmo* é **variável**, aceitando flexão em gênero e número:

1. Sentido de *semelhança*, *identidade*, *paridade*:

- Eles têm os **mesmos** gostos.
- Nós estudamos na **mesma** escola.

2. Com caráter de reforço. O próprio, não outro (inserido imediatamente após substantivo ou pronome pessoal):

- Eu **mesmo** resolvi esse problema.
- Lara e Júlia trocaram a lâmpada elas **mesmas**.

3. Utilizado de modo reflexivo, nominalmente (esse uso não é comum em Portugal):

- Na maioria das vezes analisava, eles criticavam a *si* (**mesmos**).
- Ela sempre conversa *consigo* (**mesma**).

**NOTA 1:** Embora na fonte os significados 2 e 3 estejam separados, repare que *mesmo(as)* poderia ser trocado por *próprio(as)*, então não sei dizer se de fato são significados distintos ou se podem ser aglutinados num só caso.

**NOTA 2:** Já encontrei os itens **1** e **2** sendo classificados como **pronome demonstrativo**.

---

### Locução adverbial (preposição + substantivo)

Nesse caso, *mesmo* é **variável**. Tem sentido de invariância, *"na mesma situação"*, *"no mesmo estado"*:

- Continua tudo **na mesma**.
- Tentei o que você sugeriu e deu **no mesmo**.

**NOTA:** Nunca encontrei variação no número em casos como este. *"Continua tudo 'nas mesmas'"* me soa extremamente estranho.

---

### Interrogativa "Mesmo?"

Expressão **invariável** que exprime *descrença* e *surpresa*:

- Ganhou na loteria? **Mesmo?**
- Elas foram roubadas? **Mesmo?**

---

### Com significado semelhante a "até"

Expressão **invariável** que denota *limite*:

- (Até) **mesmo** as pessoas amigas duvidaram dele.
- **Mesmo** ele, que sempre foi honesto, roubou a loja.

*Editado:*
**NOTA:** Talvez aqui sim teríamos um *advérbio de inclusão*, como no exemplo dado pelo @Jacinto.

---

### Uso comum, porém incorreto

O *mesmo* **NUNCA deve ser usado como pronome pessoal**. Repare que nos casos abaixo o *mesmo* substitui *ele(as)*, enquanto que acima, com valor de substantivo, *mesmo* tem sentido de *a mesma coisa*, *coisa semelhante*.

- Verifique se está levando consigo todos os seus objetos, pois <s>**os mesmos**</s> podem ter se deslocado durante a viagem.
- Verifique se está levando consigo todos os seus objetos, pois **eles** podem ter se deslocado durante a viagem.
- Eu entreguei o trabalho ao professor e <s>**o mesmo**</s> disse obrigado.
- Eu entreguei o trabalho ao professor e **ele** disse obrigado.

---

### Fontes principais

https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/ela-mesma-fez-ou-ela-mesmo-fez/
https://www.dicio.com.br/mesmo/
https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/fsp/fovest/fo2810200807.htm
https://comunidade.rockcontent.com/pronome-mesmo/
http://www.ufla.br/dcom/2008/10/08/o-uso-da-palavra-mesmo/
https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/mesmo-voce-sabe-utilizar-o-pronome.htm
https://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/qual-o-erro-mais-comum-ao-usar-a-palavra-mesmo/
https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf77.php

Comment: Não creio que o *mesmo* de *é uma pena mesmo* seja advérbio de inclusão. É advérbio de inclusão em coisas do tipo (exemplo do Houaiss, 2002) *mesmo o seu irmão não acreditou que ele dizia a verdade* (= *também o seu irmão, até o seu irmão*).

Comment: Acho que eu já encontrei a maioria dos usos que você meticulosamente cita. Tinha processado o "mesmo" em "uma pena mesmo" como "adjectivo de reforço", tipo "uma verdadeira pena" ou "uma pena grande". Não tinha imaginado que sirva adverbialmente neste uso, por causa da ordem das palvaras: nunca ouvi "é mesmo uma pena", por exemplo, que eu espararia ouvir dado que como advérbio, o "mesmo" modifica "é" e não "pena". Então, tal ordem seria válida (mesmo que fosse estranha)?

Comment: Outra dúvida: não estou entendendo bem a distinção entre o uso aceitável como pronome demonstativo ("dizem que o mesmo ocurrerá") e o uso comum incorreto ("pois os mesmos podem ter se deslocado"). É que o pronome no primeiro caso tem que ser usado no mesmo sentido como "isso", essencialmente para abreviar um conceito abstrato e não um objecto ou uma pessoa específica?

Comment: @Jacinto , concordo plenamente contigo. Aliás, em muitos lugares eu achei a classificação **Advérbio de afirmação** e estes sim teriam os significados de _realmente_ e _de fato_. A frase que você deu de exemplo tem bastante semelhança com a Seção "Com significado semelhante a 'até'" e fazem sentido pra mim. Inclusive, se eu tivesse em uma prova e precisasse dar algum significado para o _mesmo_ de "é uma pena mesmo" jamais colocaria _inclusão_, porque realmente gera estranheza Vou editar a resposta para acrescentar essas informações.

Comment: @jdc , quanto à sua **primeira dúvida**, "é mesmo uma pena" não soa estranho pra mim, já ouvi essa frase nessa forma diversas vezes. Então arrisco dizer que não teria problema algum em usá-la, eu mesmo usaria. Quanto à **segunda dúvida**, eu usaria a classificação de pronomes para lhe responder: usar _mesmo_ como pronome pessoal seria usá-lo como _ele(s)_ ou _ela(s)_, já como pronome demonstrativo, seria usá-lo como _isso_, _isto_, _este_ e etc., assim, na prática, seria tentar trocar o _mesmo_ por alguns desses termos para saber se o uso está correto ou não.

Comment: @jdc , não sei se consegui responder como você queria, não sou especialista em português e confesso que a sua segunda dúvida é difícil pra mim. [aqui](https://www.educacao.cc/lingua-portuguesa/pronomes-pessoais-possessivos-demonstrativos-e-outros/) tem um texto rápido sobre a classificação de pronomes e [aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronome-pessoal-vs-pronome-demonstrativo/17897) tem uma resposta sobre problemas entre pronomes demonstrativos e pessoais, talvez lhe dê alguma luz.

Comment: Leone, um mesmo advérbio pode "pertencer" a várias "classes" ou, melhor dizendo, pode exprimir diferentes noções. Assim, exemplos do [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/mesmo/), *mesmo* pode exprimir: inclusão/limite em *mesmo os santos tiveram suas fraquezas*; certeza/afirmação em *foi mesmo um grande prazer*...;  exatidão em *partiu mesmo nesse instante*. Interpretaste talvez como exaustivas as listas de advérbios em cada "classe" dos teus sites? Não são. É melhor baseares-te em dicionários, que indicam as várias noções que *mesmo* pode >>

Comment: >> transmitir. Tens também online o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/mesmo) e o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/mesmo). Eu não vi todos os sites da tua resposta, mas dos que vi nenhum diz que *mesmo* denota inclusão em *é uma pena mesmo*.

Comment: @jdc, o *mesmo* de *é uma pena mesmo* = *é mesmo uma pena* é um advérbio de frase: modifica a oração inteira e não simplesmente o verbo. Compara com o exemplo de *mesmo* enquanto advérbio de frase do Houaiss: *foi mesmo uma notícia que alegrou a todos*. Estes advérbios frequentemente vêm no início ou fim da frase: *realmente, foi uma pena* = *foi realmente uma pena* = *foi uma pena, realmente*. No exemplo do Houaiss, se substituíres *mesmo* por *realmente*, podes movê-lo para o princípio ou fim. Em Portugal ouvirás praticamente sempre *é mesmo uma pena*.

Comment: @Jacinto , desculpe, eu editei a reposta e me esqueci de arrumar o início, que era a parte mais importante. A minha pesquisa durou algumas horas e eu visitei muitos lugares, não apenas os 8 das fontes, mas não pude colocar todas as referências por conta da limitação de links, por isso, foquei nos sites que falam de _mesmo_ e de onde tirei mais informação. Ao me deparar com a classificação dos advérbios, fui atrás de sites que os classificassem no geral, não apenas o _mesmo_. De fato eles dão a entender que a classificação é fixa (bom saber que não é). Eu devia mesmo ter baseado a pesquisa >>

Comment: >> em fontes mais confiáveis, se encontrar mais algum problema, sinta-se livre para editar a minha resposta da forma que desejar!

Answer (score 3):

*Mesmo* é a forma adverbial do adjectivo *mesmo*  (o advérbio seria *mesmamente* mas essa palavra não se usa por alguma razão, mesmo [ha] que seja bem formada morfologicamente), e modifica o verbo *é* e não o substantivo *pena*. Os advérbios são invariáveis, por tanto, fica sempre como *mesmo* em frases como a que escreveste.

Comment: Ha! O uso de *mesmo* vem a propósito ("mesmo que seria"), mas não creio que tenha encontrado essa construção antes. Já ouvi *mesmo sendo* (= *apesar de ser* ou *mesmo no caso de ser*), *mesmo que seja* (= *mesmo no caso de ser*  e *mesmo que fosse* (= *se fosse*).

Comment: @Jacinto é possível ser erro meu (já sabes não é a minha língua materna).  Segundo o que estou a ler em https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-locucao-mesmo-que/26817 deve ser *mesmo que seja*  (nota que diz que tem valor condicional, seria por isso seguramente que usei, pois, o condicional haha.  Edito a resposta, obrigado!

Comment: Pois, eu pensei que quisesses dizer que *mesmamente*  não se usa, apesar de ser bem formada (valor concessivo factual). Nesse caso *mesmo que seja* não serve, pois implica que pode não ser: "compra mesmo que seja caro (pode não ser caro, porque não sabes ainda se é ou não); levanta-se sempre cedo, mesmo que seja feriado (pode não ser, porque alguns dias não são feriados). Entretanto, *mesmamente* existe mesmo (vem nos dicionários), embora de uso raro.

Comment: É isso o que queria expressar: não se usa, mas é bem formada.  Assim, recomendar-me-ias *mesmo que fosse*?  Sobre a sua existência, isso imaginava mas ao pesquisá-la, todos os exemplos de *mesmamente* que encontrei vieram do castelhano (é forma arcaica) o do asturiano (forma moderna, mas não tão usada como a forma neutra-adverbial *mesmo*)

Comment: Então a única opção segura é desistir do *mesmo que* (temos pena!): "... não se usa, apesar de ser bem formatada" ou "embora seja". É o que diz o Ciberdúvidas, as construções concessivas com *mesmo que* são hipotéticas, contrafactuais ou factual-aspectual (levanta-se cedo, mesmo que seja feriado =quando é e quando não é).

Comment: *Mesmo que fosse* é pior ainda, porque implica que não é.